# How to moq a property that will be indirectly modified?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to do a very simple thing: Set an initial value to a property, call a method which callback should modify the property value, and read the property at the end.

Class Test2 is using ITest1 to automatize some actions.

```
public interface ITest1
{
    decimal Value { get; set; }
    void Increment();
}

public class Test2
{
    ITest1 test1;
    public Test2(Itest1 test1)
    {
        this.test1 = test1;
    }

    public void Increment()
    {
        this.test1.Increment();
    }
    public Get()
    {
       return this.test1.Value;
    }
}
```

In order to achieve this behaviour I setted up this test:

```
[TestClass]
public class Test2Test
{
    private Test2 test2;
    private decimal value;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var test1Mock = new Mock<ITest1>();
        test1Mock.SetupGet(m => m.Value).Returns(value);
        test1Mock
            .Setup(m => m.Increment())
            .Callback(() => value++);

        this.test2= new Test2(test1Mock.Object);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Get_Returns0()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(0, this.test2.Get());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Get_AfterIncrement_Returns1()
    {
        this.test2.Increment();
        Assert.AreEqual(1, this.test2.Get());
    }
}
```

The second test is returning always 0. Why is this happening?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan its a typo, fixed thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MOQ - how to manually create a backing property using SetupGet/SetupSet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578269/moq-how-to-manually-create-a-backing-property-using-setupget-setupset)

Comment: If you find the answer, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to return actions instead of variables as:

`.Return(() => value)` instead of `.Return(value)`

Answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578269/moq-how-to-manually-create-a-backing-property-using-setupget-setupset).